# How to show the window title when switching windows in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome-shell, application-switcher, window-management

An upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 caused a change from Unity to GNOME 3 which means there are some things to customize. I would like to have the window switching binding (by default this is Super+Tab and Alt+Tab) show the window title, as it did in Unity. Currently, vncviewer and rdesktop windows only shows a non-descriptive word under the icon when the Alt+Tab key combination is used (and held down):

[image: nondescriptive titles]

Specifically, the second and third icon from the left only show "Vncviewer" and "rdesktop", respectively. Is there any GNOME 3 extension or other configuration (gsettings or dconf) that enable the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the [LLIax's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/879295/340383) to the [How do I "alt-tab" between windows using Gnome 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69776/how-do-i-alt-tab-between-windows-using-gnome-3) solves this problem *and* the main problem in that answer.

Note that the title shows up in the middle of the whole window but that is actually good and correct: If the title is a large string of text, you need that whole strip of real-estate for the whole title to be shown:

[image]